# Homomorphism from $S_3$ to ($\mathbb{Q},+)$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, group-homomorphism

I am solving exercise in abstract algebra and could not solve this 1 correctly.

> Does there exists a homomorphism from $S_3$ to the additive group ($\mathbb{Q},+)$ of rational numbers?

I think it exists. Map $A_3$ to $1$ and remaining elements to $-1$. But answer is no.

So, what mistake I am making? Please tell.

Comment: Your map is a homomorphism to the *multiplicative* group of non-zero rational numbers

Comment: The answer should be "yes" since there is always the trivial homomorphism $x \mapsto 0$

Comment: And in fact, the trivial homomorphism is the only homomorphism that exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\{0\}$ is the only finite subgroup of $(\Bbb Q,+)$, and hence there is no nontrivial homomorphism from any finite group $G$ to $(\Bbb Q,+)$.

Comment: Does Image of $S_3$ need to be finite ? Why ?

Comment: @Avenger, for any map $f\colon A \to B$, $a\mapsto f(a)$, the map $\tilde f\colon A\to f(A)$, $a\mapsto \tilde f(a):=f(a)$, is surjective, and hence $|f(A)|\le |A|$. Therefore, if $A$ is finite, $f(A)$ is finite as well.

Answer (score 2):

Your map is a homomorphism to the *multiplicative* group of non-zero rational numbers.

You could map every element of $S_3$ to $0$ in $\mathbb Q$

to obtain a homomorphism to the *additive* group of rational numbers.

Comment: Is it the only one?

Comment: Yes, as commented above by Daniel Schepler